# Test Class for @AuraEnabled method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, unit-test

I have written auraEnabled method using getGlobalDescribe on the "ObjectPermissions" object, not sure how can I cover this type of method. Also Please let me know if there is something good to check to write test methods for such standard things, ex - to cover userLicenses, permissionSetLicens etc.

```
  Set<String> sobjectNames = new Set<String>();
    for ( Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() ){
       Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = o.getDescribe(); 
           if(
               !objResult.getName().startsWith('packageNamespace') 
             ){
                sobjectNames.add(objResult.getName());
              }
           }     
   List<AggregateResult> plist = new List<AggregateResult>();
   plist = [SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, COUNT(SObjectType) Quantity FROM ObjectPermissions 
            WHERE (ParentId IN (SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment)) 
            AND Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true 
            AND PermissionsRead = true
            AND PermissionsCreate = false
            AND PermissionsDelete = false
            AND PermissionsEdit = false
            AND PermissionsModifyAllRecords = false
            AND PermissionsViewAllRecords = false
            AND (SObjectType IN :sobjectNames) 
            GROUP BY Parent.Profile.Name];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your test you can simply call the method:

```
Map<String,List<Boolean>> actual = YourClassName.getProfileWithObjects(pfr);
```

as the `@AuraEnabled` annotation adds special handling provided by the platform rather than takes anything away from the static method call capability.

**PS**

On testing calls that check things like licenses, those objects are probably 8n the category of [data that is not isolated from unit tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm). But also you cannot update those objects so you have to rely on the default set that is in an org and write your tests to match those.

Comment: Okay, got it and how can I cover the licence information fetching methods like I am fetching UserLicenses and permissionSetLicense. I have edit the question with that method ?

Comment: @Ashutosh Can you re-instate your original question and either add to it or perhaps better add a new question? The idea of this site is to keep a record of both the questions and answers.